# Japanese sentence regex capturing punctuation separately

Tags: ruby, regex

I am attempting to seperate blocks of Japanese text into individual sentences using regex. Right now I'm mostly experimenting on [rubular](http://rubular.com) but here is what I have so far.

regex: `/(.*?(。|？|！))/`

sample text

> 強面のため周囲の人から敬遠されている主人公が、クラスメイトと共通の話題を持とうとVRMMORPG「アナザーワールド」のベータテストに申し込んだ。ところが当選したのは彼一人。しかたなくひとりでゲーム内の仮想世界「イストピア」に「ケイオス」と名乗って乗り込んだが、そこはゲームでありながら五感すべてを体感でき、現実と間違えるほどのリアルな世界だった。サポートAIのテミスの協力を得つつ、クエストをこなしていったが、実はそこは本物の異世界「イストピア」であり、ケイオスのこなしたクエストによって、多くの人が影響を受けて……というお話。その戯言、聞き飽きたわ！あれ、ここにあった筆入れはどこにやったの？

The results im getting are correct however it is also separately matching the punctuation characters [image: matches]

How can I improve my regular expression so that the punctuation mark isn't separately matched?

Comment: Check http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#label-Character+Properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `(.*?[。？！])` seems to do the trick, check on [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/BB0d2rSQ1i)

```
Match 1
1.  強面のため周囲の人から敬遠されている主人公が、クラスメイトと共通の話題を持とうとVRMMORPG「アナザーワールド」のベータテストに申し込んだ。
Match 2
1.  ところが当選したのは彼一人。
Match 3
1.  しかたなくひとりでゲーム内の仮想世界「イストピア」に「ケイオス」と名乗って乗り込んだが、そこはゲームでありながら五感すべてを体感でき、現実と間違えるほどのリアルな世界だった。
Match 4
1.  サポートAIのテミスの協力を得つつ、クエストをこなしていったが、実はそこは本物の異世界「イストピア」であり、ケイオスのこなしたクエストによって、多くの人が影響を受けて……というお話。
Match 5
1.  その戯言、聞き飽きたわ！
Match 6
1.  あれ、ここにあった筆入れはどこにやったの？
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
str.scan /[\p{Han}\p{Katakana}\p{Hiragana}\p{Hangul}[[:punct:]]]+/
=> ["強面のため周囲の人から敬遠されている主人公が、クラスメイトと共通の話題を持とうと",
 "「アナザ",
 "ワ",
 "ルド」のベ",
 "タテストに申し込んだ。ところが当選したのは彼一人。しかたなくひとりでゲ",
 "ム内の仮想世界「イストピア」に「ケイオス」と名乗って乗り込んだが、そこはゲ",
 "ムでありながら五感すべてを体感でき、現実と間違えるほどのリアルな世界だった。サポ",
 "ト",
 "のテミスの協力を得つつ、クエストをこなしていったが、実はそこは本物の異世界「イストピア」であり、ケイオス    のこなしたクエストによって、多くの人が影響を受けて……というお話。その戯言、聞き飽きたわ！あれ、ここにあった筆入れはどこにやったの？"]
```

http://rubular.com/r/8CtYuV8AAl